# Does tensorflow support the un-normalized loss?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm doing semantic segmentation using tensorflow framework. My question is, does the tensorflow support the un-normalized loss for softmax with cross-entropy, for example as follows:

https://github.com/torrvision/caffe/blob/d779ee369bf86739bc225d99e78aefa040da199f/src/caffe/layers/softmax_loss_layer.cpp#L115

Comment: Maybe we could get the un-normalized loss by multiplying the obtained loss one constant? Is there any data overflow problem for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to follow what's going on in that file. I believe by "unnormalized" you mean that the output of softmax produces values in the [0,1] range which don't need to sum to 1, such as is used by multi-class classification.

If I'm right, you're simply looking for `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(...)` which applies sigmoid on the output layer. Each output neuron produces a value in the [0,1] range, but they are independent of each other.

This is what you should use for multi-class classification.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your kind answer! The `normalized` is defined in [https://github.com/torrvision/caffe/blob/d779ee369bf86739bc225d99e78aefa040da199f/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L415], which means "normalize each batch across all instances (including spatial dimesions, but not ignored instances);"